# Why can Python script not import module installed to a virtual environment via pip when called from a batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file, virtualenv, python-venv

I have written a batch file that shall do the following:

- Create a virtual environment
- Activate the virtual environment
- Install a module from a GitHub repository using pip within the virtual environment
- Execute a python script that imports said module within the virtual environment

Here is some exemplary code that gives an idea on what I already have:

The batch file: `file.bat`

```
python3 -m venv myenv
call .\myenv\Scripts\activate
pip install git+https://github.com/user/themodule_repo.git
python script.py
```

The Python script: `script.py`

```
import themodule
themodule.function()
```

`script.py` returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'themodule'` but the module itself can be found in `.\myenv\Lib\site-packages\themodule`.

Executing `file.bat` from command line `script.py` returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'themodule'` but the module itself can be found in `.\myenv\Lib\site-packages\themodule`.

When I execute the following commands manually in command line, everything works as expected.

```
C:\somepath> python3 -m venv myenv
C:\somepath> .\myenv\Scripts\activate
(myenv) C:\somepath> pip install git+https://github.com/user/themodule_repo.git
(myenv) C:\somepath> python

>>> import themodule
>>> themodule.function()
>>>
```

I'm using Python 3.9.5 on Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: If the module is correctly installed in your venv by your BAT file, the creation of the venv and installation must have worked. So the only remaining possibility is that you are calling a Python interpreter that is not in your venv. Add the following two lines to the very start of your Python script `import sys` then `print(sys.executable, sys.path)`

Comment: `pip3` and `python3` both look like names in the global environment; I though `venv` only installed `pip` and `python` to the virtual environment.

Comment: @chepner: My mistake. In my original script which I can unfortunately not share due to contained company internal information, I only used python3 to create the venv. From then on I only used pip and python. Corrected that above.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: All printed paths are within the venv.